# enable CDI alternatives on other app's beans.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, java-ee-7

I have an alternative in my app, that looks like this:

```
@Alternative
public class MyAlternative { ... }
```

And it works when enabled on my app's beans.xml, as expected.

However, I'd like to enable this alternative in the beans.xml of another app

that's using a jar with this alternative. Is it possible?

Comment: I think you need something like the Produces annotation.

Answer (score -1):

In CDI 1.1+, you can use a `@Priority` annotation to enable an alternative [for a whole application](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#declaring_selected_alternatives).

Comment: yes hwellmann, but how @Priority would help me in that case? I need the bean to be disabled by default, and only enabled if the user wants.

Comment: the answer is not helpful for that case